# Как лучше организовать запуск/остановку потоков в Java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Друзья, подскажите, как правильнее организовать работу потоков в следующем случае.
Поток, созданный для перебора неких объектов (предположим директории),

```
public class Processor extends Thread{

    private Object obj;

    public Processor(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Some business logic with resultObj
        obj = resultObj;
        Processor newLinkProcessor = new Processor(obj);
        newLinkProcessor.start();
        try {
            newLinkProcessor.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
            interruptedException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

вызывает такой же поток и ждёт его, чтобы потом продолжить.

Есть три кнопки со слушателями:

1. 1-ая должна запускать задачу, либо возобновлять её, если та была
   поставлена на паузу.
2. 2-ая ставить её на паузу, чтобы все потоки приостанавливались, но
   могли быть, потом продолжены после нажатия 1-ой кнопки.
3. 3-ья сбрасывать задачу, чтобы при дальнейшем нажатии 1-ой кнопки,
   она запускалась заново.

?Вопрос: Как лучше организовать запуск, остановку, паузу/воспроизведение и соответствующее хранение всех этих потоков, чтобы их иерархия(один поток ждёт выполнения другого и тд.) и прогресс выполнения сохранялись?
Подойдёт ли ArryaList для их хранения?
Можно ли сделать через wait() и notify() или же как-то можно сделать через цикл и interrupt() (isInterrupted())?